# Is it possible get one by one document once signed from bulk send?

Tags: docusignapi

We have bulk send feature on Docusign by which we can send the document to mulitple envelopes which would be signed by many from the list. So each of them would be getting their own copy of the document to sign. So, is it possible to download the document as the receipent(s) signed it. We can download the document with mulitple users and single sign document once it is completed by registering the webhook. Is it possible to get this in same way for bulk send also? Can we get the document one by one as the receipents from the list signs that ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question. We're not customer support for [your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Answer (score 0):

Bulk Send generates multiple envelopes, each envelope for a CSV row, so DocuSign Connect will help you getting notified for each envelope.

Using DocuSign Connect, you can subscribe to Recipient Level Trigger events - For instace Recipient Signed/Completed, once any recipient signs the envelope then you will receive the notification from the DocuSign, on receiving the notification you can call DS API to download the document or you can include documents in the DocuSign Connect message itself if the document is not very big.